# Need to tune the select query without adding index

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, join, performance-testing

I have a query related to Indexes and Execution plan. Below are few tables that I am using

**Table 1 : TestReviewResult**

Column_name            |Type    |Length

TestReviewResultId     |int     |4

TestNumber             |int     |4

ReviewerUserId         |int     |4

**Current Index**

index_name  index_description   index_keys

TestReviewResult_PK clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   TestReviewResultId

**Table 2: TestReviewFinding**

Column_name Type    Length

TestReviewFindingId int 4

TestReviewResultId  int 4

ScreenCode  varchar 100

ReviewComments  varchar 8000

**CurrentIndex**

index_name  index_description   index_keys

TestReviewFinding_PK    clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   TestReviewFindingId

**Table3: TestReviewResultComment**

Column_name Type    Length

TestReviewResultCommentId   Int 4

TestReviewResultId  Int 4

TestReviewComment   varchar 8000

**CurrentIndex**

index_name  index_description   index_keys

TestReviewResultComment_CI  clustered located on PRIMARY    TestReviewResultId

TestReviewResultComment_PK  nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY    TestReviewResultCommentId

**Table 4: TestReviewFindingElement**

Column_name Type    Length

TestReviewFindingElementId  Int 4

TestReviewFindingId Int 4

ElementCode varchar 25

**CurrentIndex**

index_name  index_description   index_keys

TestReviewFindingElementType_PK clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   TestReviewFindingElementId

Below is the query that is being used

```
Select columnnames…. from 
From TestReviewResult(NOLOCK) cr 
left outer join TestReviewResultComment(NOLOCK) crc

 on cr.TestReviewResultId = crc.TestReviewResultId

 left outer join TestReviewFinding(NOLOCK) cf

 on cf.TestReviewResultId = cr.TestReviewResultId

 left outer join TestReviewFindingElement(NOLOCK) crf

on cf.TestReviewFindingId = crf.TestReviewFindingId

 where cr.TestReviewResultId = @TestReviewNumber  -- Test Review number is 
 being passed in the stored procedure
```

When I ran the Execution plan it suggested to add 2 indexes  mentioned below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestReviewResultId
ON [TestReviewFinding] (TestReviewResultId)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestReviewFindingId
 ON [TestReviewFindingElement] (TestReviewFindingId)
```

Is there any alternative way I can tune the above query without adding indexes as there are lot of write operations that do get performed

Below is the ddl that you can execute in SQL Server and check the Query execution Plan

```
Create table TestReviewResult(
TestReviewResultId        int            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
TestNumber      int          ,
ReviewerUserId              int          )


insert into TestReviewResult values(1,1,1)
insert into TestReviewResult values(2,2,2)
insert into TestReviewResult values(3,3,3)






    Create table TestReviewFinding(
    TestReviewFindingId      int          not null primary key,
TestReviewResultId        int          ,
ScreenCode       varchar(100))

insert into TestReviewFinding values(1,1,'A')
insert into TestReviewFinding values(2,2,'B')
insert into TestReviewFinding values(3,3,'C')




Create table TestReviewResultComment(
TestReviewResultCommentId    int not null primary key     nonclustered,
TestReviewResultId    int    ,
TestReviewComment     varchar(      8000)

)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_TestReviewResultId]   
    ON TestReviewResultComment (TestReviewResultId); 

insert into TestReviewResultComment values(1,1,'A')
insert into TestReviewResultComment values(2,2,'B')

insert into TestReviewResultComment values(3,3,'C')






Create table TestReviewFindingElement(
TestReviewFindingElementId   int    not null primary key,
TestReviewFindingId   int    ,
ElementCode   varchar(25))


insert into TestReviewFindingElement values(1,1,'A')
insert into TestReviewFindingElement values(2,3,'B')
insert into TestReviewFindingElement values(3,3,'C')
```

When I m running the below query I am getting Index scans on 2 tables
TestReviewFindingElement and TestReviewFinding

```
Select *
From TestReviewResult(NOLOCK) cr 
left outer join TestReviewResultComment(NOLOCK) crc

 on cr.TestReviewResultId = crc.TestReviewResultId

  left outer join TestReviewFinding(NOLOCK) cf

  on cf.TestReviewResultId = cr.TestReviewResultId

  left outer join TestReviewFindingElement(NOLOCK) crf

 on cf.TestReviewFindingId = crf.TestReviewFindingId
 where cr.TestReviewResultId = @TestReviewNumber  -- Test Review number is 
  being passed in the stored procedure.You can use --> 1
```

Is there any way to modify the select query to avoid scan without adding index

Comment: can you add schema of table as ddl and provide test data.you can script the schema with statistics,so that we can repro the issues

Comment: I have added ddl and insert scripts ...can you please check and let me know if we can get execution plan to return seek instead of scans

Comment: Based on the SQL provided, its not filtering on any of the columns (meaning there is no where clause with an equal to condition specific to a column value). So pretty much you are asking to scan the entire index/table by those joins. In this particular case, scanning table is faster than index scan and then retrieve rows from table.

Comment: added the where clause